# lists getting the value: display: list-item and discs in front

Tags: css, browser

my li's are getting display: list-item; automatically from the browser and have disc's in front, I tried the list-style-type:none; but it doesn't work, the only thing that works is display: inline; then the discs disappear but it messes up all their positions. How can I remove the display: list-item;?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about what it is you are wanting to achieve? Alternatively, put an example up on jsfiddle.com

Comment: I have never used jsfiddle and this has never happened to me before, I have a form which has its fields organized by ul li and has discs before every li, it looks like it has list-style-type: disc; but it doesnt! the problem that is causing those discs is the display: list-item!

Comment: @TooCooL you're going to have to recreate the problem for us, as using `list-style-type: none;` on either the `ul` or `li` works. Please post the css and html code for the list that makes the problem. Or update this jsfiddle to show us a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrH96/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it on the ul not the li

```
ul{list-style-type:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem, there was a background picture in front of all li's, now I removed it and  solved the problem, I am sorry for confusing you guys, thank you